# How do I know what file wasn't found when java gives the error "The system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: java

I'm getting the following exception in my code and I'm uncertain which file the system cannot find.  Is it the command I'm executing that cannot be found `gfortran.exe` or is it a dynamic library that gfortran depends on?  How can I tell, and which file is the one that cannot be found?

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:376)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gfortran.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Jason Zwolak\AppData\Local\Temp\pet2-biopack-Jason Zwolak"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at com.insilicalabs.pet2.publish.mpf.BiopackCompiler.compile(BiopackCompiler.java:154)
[catch] at com.insilicalabs.pet2.publish.mpf.PublishToMPFProvider.publishImpl(PublishToMPFProvider.java:190)
    at com.insilicalabs.pet2.publish.mpf.PublishToMPFProvider.access$000(PublishToMPFProvider.java:60)
    at com.insilicalabs.pet2.publish.mpf.PublishToMPFProvider$1.run(PublishToMPFProvider.java:67)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1432)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2044)
```

**UPDATE**

To clarify, if `gfortran.exe` is the file that cannot be found, will this always be the case with an error like this?  Or could it be that a shared library cannot be found?  How do I know which file cannot be found?

Comment: Uh, look at the message?  `Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gfortran.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Jason Zwolak\AppData\Local\Temp\pet2-biopack-Jason Zwolak"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: @HotLicks: That tells us that it couldn't run the program, and the reason was a file not found error, **not** that the file that couldn't be found was `gfortran.exe`. Read the question: Could it be a library that `gfortran.exe` relies on?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - What other file would it be?  The directory specified is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: This is an error on GFortran execution and not jvm execution. This output is from GFortran I think.

Comment: @HotLicks: Was there a part of "...a library that `gfortran.exe` relies on..." that was unclear?

Comment: @AlexanderJardim: Almost certainly not, look at the stack trace.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - The error message came from Java's ProcessBuilder.start, not from the gfortran program.  gfortran would have had to be started to find any missing support files.

Comment: @HotLicks: It's been a long time since I was deep into .exe loading details. I seem to remember there are times when the OS (rather than the .exe) loads certain required files listed in a dependencies section (usually not by explicit filename, but by some indirect reference), but perhaps not (or perhaps not in this case), it may be pre-baked startup code supplied by the standard runtime. In any case, there's no need to be rude to the OP about the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let us go through this, step by step.

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "gfortran.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\Jason Zwolak\AppData\Local\Temp\pet2-biopack-Jason Zwolak"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

If you look at the end of the line, it states that `gfortran.exe` cannot be found in the directory listed, or "The system cannot find the file specified."

Now, this will always be the case, IF the file cannot be found.
So the file can't be found, not the command.

We know that this isn't a library that depends of gfortran.exe or the library would be explicitly stated that the error is caused by a dependency in the stack.

This exception can be thrown when a file exists, but can't be accessed. This happens when file permissions don't allow reading or writing, etc.

Addressing the issue of ambiguity, if the system can't run a program, and the file listed cannot be found, assume it is a file that can't be found, and gfortran.exe is that file. To be sure that the program itself can't be run because of a file that can't be found (Which would be explicitly stated.), check `at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)`

Comment: I don't think it's safe to draw that conclusion. Java doesn't know anything about what the operating system has to do to execute a program. All it knows is the error code the operating system returns. You may or may not be correct in your assertions here.

Comment: It would include the library information within the Exception. It would state the class name of an external library and the errors.

Comment: @CoonKitteh: Re-read EJP's comment. The Java runtime *may not know* what file wasn't found.

Comment: You have a point, but it would still show the file name that isn't found at `at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)`

Comment: Notice that Java says "Cannot _run_ program ".  The reason I bothered to ask this question is because when I got this error I went and ran the gfortran from the command line and received a popup window that said "cannot find ..." some shared library file.  So I then wanted to know if Java couldn't find gfortran because my path was wrong or could not find the shared file.  It took a while to figure out.

Comment: The link @CoonKitteh gives to the JavaSE API is about the FileNotFoundException... notice that I did not receive a FileNotFoundException.  The exception is an IOException!!